# Extracting values from JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the JSON data given below. The 'crop' array contains multiple array of crop price, I want to get average crop price of all districts(using 'district_id').

```
    <i>{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 7,
    "crop": [
        {
            "id": "133",
            "crop_id": "81",
            "price": "45.00",
            "description": null,
            "user_id": "27",
            "block_id": "1",
            "longitude": "87.8661808",
            "latitude": "23.2340073",
            "date": "2014-02-03",
            "time": "12:44:43",
            "district_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "135",
            "crop_id": "81",
            "price": "10.50",
            "description": null,
            "user_id": "27",
            "block_id": "1",
            "longitude": "87.8662402",
            "latitude": "23.2339822",
            "date": "2014-02-03",
            "time": "12:44:54",
            "district_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "143",
            "crop_id": "81",
            "price": "35",
            "description": null,
            "user_id": "27",
            "block_id": "1",
            "longitude": "0.0",
            "latitude": "0.0",
            "date": "2014-02-03",
            "time": "13:12:50",
            "district_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "146",
            "crop_id": "81",
            "price": "85",
            "description": null,
            "user_id": "27",
            "block_id": "1",
            "longitude": "0.0",
            "latitude": "0.0",
            "date": "2014-02-03",
            "time": "14:29:07",
            "district_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "148",
            "crop_id": "81",
            "price": "25",
            "description": null,
            "user_id": "27",
            "block_id": "1",
            "longitude": "0.0",
            "latitude": "0.0",
            "date": "2014-02-03",
            "time": "14:58:01",
            "district_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "132",
            "crop_id": "81",
            "price": "10",
            "description": null,
            "user_id": "119",
            "block_id": "34",
            "longitude": "0.0",
            "latitude": "0.0",
            "date": "2014-02-03",
            "time": "12:41:49",
            "district_id": "4"
        },
        {
            "id": "134",
            "crop_id": "81",
            "price": "12",
            "description": null,
            "user_id": "119",
            "block_id": "34",
            "longitude": "0.0",
            "latitude": "0.0",
            "date": "2014-02-03",
            "time": "12:43:50",
            "district_id": "4"
        }
    ]
}</i>
```

Comment: How about decode your json first using `json_decode` func.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have too decode the JSON using `json_decode` function, then access using variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use  `json_decode` method to convert it to an `std_class` or use the 2nd parameter of this method to convert it to an associated array.

Take a look at https://www.php.net/json_decode

Once you decode it, you can easily access the variables like accessing properties of a class or as an array object if you are converting to an associated array

Answer (score 0):

Do like this..

```
//Assign your JSON data to this $json variable as shown in the demo.
$arr = json_decode($json,1);
foreach($arr['crop'] as $arr1)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($arr1['district_id']==1)
        {
            $avgpr[] = $arr1['price'];
        }
    }
}

echo $avgprice = array_sum($avgpr)/count($avgpr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
40.1
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/97733)